# Logging Tomcat Http input?

Tags: tomcat

I must have looked at 2 dozen websites, but nothing I've tried has spewed the data I'm looking for yet. I'm running Tomcat 6 and I want to spew the actual Http request contents. Well, it's a Post. My real goal is to see the actual SOAP request in all it's glory. I'm trying to debug a customer request issue, but I need to see the actual contents of the request to figure it out.

Seems like this should be trivial, but I've yet to find the log4j (or other setting) that causes Tomcat to log this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the RequestDumperValve to do this - I think it dumps out the POST contents.

See the [Tomcat manual for how-to](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/valve.html#Request_Dumper_Valve).